# How to Filter by Category via Modal using checkbox Ionic / Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have 3 types of filters:

**One of research:**

```
<div class="bar bar-subheader bar-assertive">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper textbox-search">
        <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" aria-label="filter restaurantess" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Where the ng-model filter is: *| filter: q*

**One per order by:**

```
<!-- ORDER BY -->
            <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-restaurant" modal-select="" ng-model="someModel" options="selectableNames" option-property="role" modal-title="Ordenar por..." has-search="true">Ordenar
                <div class="option">
                    <h2>{{option.name}}</h2>
                </div>
            </button>
```

Where the filter is: *| orderBy: someModel*

**And I need a Category filter**, which opens a modal listing all the categories, but showing only the categories that are listed (for the user not to waste time selecting a category that does not exist in the list), where the View of this modal is:

```
<ion-modal view-title="cadastrar" hide-nav-bar="false">
<ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Choice the Categories</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            Estão sendo listadas apenas as categorias existentes em sua localização.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-bar">
        <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-funnel" ng-click="save()">Aplicar Filtro</button>
    </div>

    <ion-list>
        <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in ofertass | unique:'categoria_comida_nome' track by $index" ng-model="filtro[$index]" ng-true-value="{{item}}" ng-false-value="" ng-checked="check">{{item.categoria_comida_nome}}</ion-checkbox>
    </ion-list>

    <div class="button-bar">
        <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-funnel" ng-click="save()">Aplicar Filtro</button>
    </div>


</ion-content>
```

As in the following image, **the result of modal code**:

[Modal View result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sujcJ.png)

Ordering and search are working well.

But **I'm not getting a way to filter the categories selected by the user.**

**To illustrate better**, it follows the complete View (html) of my main listing which I want to filter the categories:

```
   <ion-view side="center" view-title="vovócooks">


<!-- BOTÃO CARRINHO DE COMPRAS -->
<ion-nav-buttons side="right" class="has-header">
    <a href="#/nhaac/carrinho" class="button button-clear button-icon icon ion-ios-cart"> {{total}} </a>

    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-ios-color-filter-outline" id="menu-popover" ng-click="popover.show($event)"></button>

</ion-nav-buttons>

<center>
    <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-assertive">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper textbox-search">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" aria-label="filter restaurantess" />
        </label>
    </div>
</center>


<div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-assertive tabs-color-light">
    <div class="tabs" style="height:70px;">
        <a class="tab-item active" href="#/nhaac/promocoes">
            <i class="icon ion-home"></i> DELÍCIAS CASEIRAS
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" href="#/nhaac/restaurantes">
            <i class="icon ion-star"></i> VOVÓS ONLINE
        </a>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="tabs-striped tabs-color-assertive" >
    <div class="tabs">
        <a class="tab-item active" ng-click="doRefresh()">
            <i class="icon ion-refresh"></i> Atualizar
        </a>

        <a ng-show="checarPermissoes('logado_usuario')" class="tab-item" href="#/nhaac/perfil">
            <i class="icon ion-person"></i> Meu Perfil
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<ion-content delegate-handle="top" lazy-scroll id="page-promocoes" class="has-header page-promocoes">

    <ion-refresher pulling-text="Puxe para atualizar..." on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>


    <div class="list animate-fade-slide-in-right">

        <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 65px;"></div>

            <div class="card" >
                  <div class="item" style="white-space:normal;font-size:12px">
                      <center>
                      <b>Sua localização atual é: </b> {{endereco_atual}}
                      </center>
                    </div>  

                     <center>
                          <button class="button button-clear button-assertive" style="font-size:12px" ui-sref="nhaac.localiza">
                              Mudar Localização
                          </button>
                      </center> 

             </div>      

        <div class="button-bar">

            <!-- FILTER BY CATEGORY... -->
            <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-funnel" ng-click="abreModal()">
                Filtrar
            </button>


            <!-- ORDER BY -->
            <button class="button button-stable button-block  icon-left ion-android-restaurant" modal-select="" ng-model="someModel" options="selectableNames" option-property="role" modal-title="Ordenar por..." has-search="true">Ordenar
                <div class="option">
                    <h2>{{option.name}}</h2>
                </div>
            </button>

        </div>



        <div class="card" ng-repeat="item in ofertass | filter:q | orderBy:someModel | unique: 'cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta'" ng-init="$last ? fireEvent() : null" href="#/nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}">



            <div class="item item-thumbnail-top item-text-wrap">
                <img class="imagemCapa" image-lazy-loader="lines" ng-src="{{item.cadastra_oferta_foto}}" />
                <div class="promocao"><b>{{item.cadastra_oferta_desconto}}% Off</b></div>
                <div class="desconto"><b>{{item.cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto | currency}}</b></div>

                <div class="item">
                    <center>
                        <h2 style="white-space:normal; color:#D95B43;"><b>{{item.cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao}}</b></h2>
                    </center>
                </div>

                <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 8px;"></div>

                <h3><b>Vovó Cozinheira: </b>{{item.fornecedores_fantasia}}</h3>

                <div ng-model="item.avaliacao_media">

                    <div ng-show="item.avaliacao_media">
                        <!--                            <h4>Avaliação Média:  {{item.avaliacao_media}} </h4> -->


                        <h4>Avaliação Média

                            <span class="stars alignleft">
                        <span ng-style="{ 'width': getStars(item.avaliacao_media) }">
                    </span></h4>



                    </div>





                    <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 8px;"></div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <h3>Categoria: {{item.categoria_comida_nome}}</h3>

                        <h3><small><b>Descrição: </b>{{item.cadastra_oferta_descricao}}</small></h3>

                        <h3>
                            Preço Normal: <s style="color:red;"><small class="preco"> {{item.cadastra_oferta_valor_sem_desconto | currency}}</small></s><br> Preço Promocional: <small class="preco"> {{item.cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto | currency}} </small><br> Preço do Frete: <small class="preco"> {{item.fornecedor_configura_frete_custo_padrao | currency}} </small>

                        </h3>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <a class="item button button-clear button-assertive ink" href="#nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}"><b>PEDIR</b></a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <ion-list class="list">
        <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="onInfinite()" distance="5px" ng-if="hasMoreData"></ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list class="list">
        <div class="item" ng-if="results.length == 0">
            <p>Nenhum resultado encontrado...</p>
        </div>
    </ion-list>


</ion-content>
<!-- ./content -->
```

In my Controller, what **I try** to filter by ng-click the excerpt is this:

```
// PEGA OS ITENS SELECIONADOS NA MODAL E COLOCA NUM ARRAY
    $scope.checkItems = {};

    $scope.print = function () {
        console.log($scope.checkItems);
    }

    // APLICANDO FILTRO CATEGORIA
    $scope.userCategoria = function (checkItems) {
        console.log("entra na chamada");

        $scope.modal.hide();


    };

    $scope.save = function (checkItems) {
        console.log("Chamou o save");
        var array = [];
        for (i in $scope.checkItems) {
            console.log($scope.checkItems[i]);
            if ($scope.checkItems[i] == true) {
                array.push(i);

            }
        }
        console.log(array);

        $scope.MeuFiltro = array;

        console.log("Selecionado final: "+ $scope.MeuFiltro);


        window.localStorage.setItem("filtros", array);

        $scope.modal.hide();
    }
```

This is pretty messed up with so many tests I've done ...

But you can see that I get the data, and store it locally separated by commas:

[CONSOLE RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ewkl.png)

That is, **I am suffering** with the return **(ignorance) ...**

If I post ***| GroupBy: 'mais_campo'*** gives error.

**I can´t make do the filter by categories, and I need help.**

**Or do I need to change logic?** I do not know if for lack of a better logic **(or knowledge)**. **Would greatly appreciate ...**

Well, to finish, I make available **my entire Controller:**

```
     .controller("promocoesCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicScrollDelegate, $http, $httpParamSerializer, $stateParams, $timeout, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $ionicPopover, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicHistory, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion, $ionicModal, sharedCartService, sharedFilterService) {

        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
            disableBack: false,
            historyRoot: true
        });


        //put cart after menu
        var cart = sharedCartService.cart;

        $scope.endereco_atual = window.localStorage.getItem("endereco_atual");

        if (window.localStorage.getItem("user_des") === undefined) {
            console.log("Usuário logado, setar como logado");



        } else {

            console.log("Usuário deslogado, setar como deslogado");
            var setar = "user_des";
            window.localStorage.setItem("user_des", setar)
        };


        $scope.getStars = function (avalia) {
            // Get the value
            var val = parseFloat(avalia);
            // Turn value into number/100
            var size = val / 6 * 100;
            return size + '%';
        }

        $scope.cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor = $stateParams.cadastra_oferta_cod_fornecedor;

        $scope.endereco_atual = window.localStorage.getItem("endereco_atual");


        // ORDENA POR...
        $scope.selectableNames = [

            {
                name: "Por preço: Do Menor para o Maior",
                role: "+cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto"
        },

            {
                name: "Por preço: Do Maior para o Menor",
                role: "-cadastra_oferta_valor_com_desconto"
        },

            {
                name: "Por Maior Desconto (%)",
                role: "-cadastra_oferta_desconto"
        },

            {
                name: "Menor Prazo de Entrega",
                role: "+fornecedor_configura_frete_prazo_entrega_min"
        },

            {
                name: "Maior Prazo de Entrega",
                role: "-fornecedor_configura_frete_prazo_entrega_min"
        },

            {
                name: "Oferta em Ordem Alfabética",
                role: "+cadastra_oferta_titulo_promocao"
        },

            {
                name: "Por Categoria",
                role: "+categoria_comida_nome"
        },



//        {
//            name: "Por Menor valor de Frete",
//            role: "+fornecedor_configura_frete_custo_padrao"
//        },

    ];


        $scope.getOpt = function (option) {
            return option.name + ":" + option.role;
            console.log(option);
            window.localstorage.setItem("OrdenaPor", option.role);
        };
        // FIM DE ORDENA POR


        // PEGA OS ITENS SELECIONADOS NA MODAL E COLOCA NUM ARRAY
        $scope.checkItems = {};

        $scope.print = function () {
            console.log($scope.checkItems);
        }

        // APLICANDO FILTRO CATEGORIA
        $scope.userCategoria = function (checkItems) {
            console.log("entra na chamada");

            $scope.modal.hide();


        };

        $scope.save = function (checkItems) {
            console.log("Chamou o save");
            var array = [];
            for (i in $scope.checkItems) {
                console.log($scope.checkItems[i]);
                if ($scope.checkItems[i] == true) {
                    array.push(i);

                }
            }
            console.log(array);

            $scope.MeuFiltro = array;

            console.log("Selecionado final: "+ $scope.MeuFiltro);


            window.localStorage.setItem("filtros", array);

            $scope.modal.hide();
        }




        // INICIA FILTRO POR CATEGORIA    
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('/templates/filters/side-filter.html', {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function (modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
        });
        $scope.abreModal = function () {
            $scope.modal.show();
        };
        $scope.closeModal = function () {
            $scope.modal.hide();


        };

        // FIM FILTRO POR CATEGORIA



        $rootScope.page_id = "promocoes";

        $scope.endereco_atual = window.localStorage.getItem("endereco_atual");


        $scope.scrollTop = function () {
            $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle("top").scrollTop();
        };
        // open external browser 
        $scope.openURL = function ($url) {
            window.open($url, "_system", "location=yes");
        };
        // open AppBrowser
        $scope.openAppBrowser = function ($url) {
            window.open($url, "_blank", "closebuttoncaption=Done");
        };
        // open WebView
        $scope.openWebView = function ($url) {
            window.open($url, "_self");
        };

        // Set Motion
        $timeout(function () {
            ionicMaterialMotion.slideUp({
                selector: ".slide-up"
            });
        }, 300);


        var targetQuery = ""; //default param
        var raplaceWithQuery = "";
        // TODO: Dinamics Promoções

        $scope.endereco_atual = window.localStorage.getItem("endereco_atual");

        targetQuery = "json=promocao"; //default param
        raplaceWithQuery = "json=promocao";


        var fetch_per_scroll = 1;
        // animation loading 
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<div class="loader"><svg class="circular"><circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></svg></div>'
        });


        $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false; //readmore status
        var lastPush = 0;
        var data_ofertass = [];

        if (window.localStorage.getItem("data_ofertass") !== "undefined") {
            data_ofertass = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("data_ofertass"));
            if (data_ofertass !== null) {
                $scope.ofertass = [];
                for (lastPush = 0; lastPush < 10; lastPush++) {
                    if (angular.isObject(data_ofertass[lastPush])) {
                        $scope.ofertass.push(data_ofertass[lastPush]);
                    };
                }

                $timeout(function () {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, 500);


            }
        }
        if (!angular.isObject(data_ofertass)) {
            $timeout(function () {
                // retry retrieving data
                $http.get("http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_oferta_api.php?json=promocao".replace(targetQuery, raplaceWithQuery)).then(function (response) {
                    data_ofertass = response.data;
                    if (typeof (Storage) != "undefined") {
                        try {
                            window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(data_ofertass));
                        } catch (e) {
                            window.localStorage.clear();
                            window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(data_ofertass));
                            $state.reload();
                            $scope.$state = $state;
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.ofertass = [];
                    for (lastPush = 0; lastPush < 100; lastPush++) {
                        if (angular.isObject(data_ofertass[lastPush])) {
                            $scope.ofertass.push(data_ofertass[lastPush]);
                        };
                    }
                }, function (response) {
                    // error message
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: "error " + response.status,
                        template: response.statusText + "<br/>problem: table ofertas",
                    });
                }).finally(function () {
                    $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
                    // event done, hidden animation loading
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                    }, 1000);
                });

            }, 1000);
        }




        $scope.doRefresh = function () {
            // retry retrieving data
            //  window.localStorage.clear();
            $http.get("http://vovocooks.com.br/admin/apis/api_listagem/lista_oferta_api.php?json=promocao".replace(targetQuery, raplaceWithQuery)).then(function (response) {
                data_ofertass = response.data;
                if (typeof (Storage) != "undefined") {
                    try {
                        window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(data_ofertass));
                    } catch (e) {
                        window.localStorage.clear();
                        window.localStorage.setItem("data_ofertass", JSON.stringify(data_ofertass));
                        //   $ionicHistory.removeBackView();
                        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
                        //    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
                        $state.reload();
                        $scope.$state = $state;


                    }
                }
                $scope.ofertass = [];
                for (lastPush = 0; lastPush < 100; lastPush++) {
                    if (angular.isObject(data_ofertass[lastPush])) {
                        $scope.ofertass.push(data_ofertass[lastPush]);
                    };
                }
            }, function (response) {
                // error message
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: "error " + response.status,
                    template: response.statusText + "<br/>Problema: com a tabela de ofertas",
                });
            }).finally(function () {
                $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
                // event done, hidden animation loading
                $timeout(function () {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, 500);
            });



        };


        if (data_ofertass === null) {
            data_ofertass = [];
        };

        //Coloca produto em destaque
        $scope.addToStar = function (id, image, name, price, supply_id, deliver) {

            console.log(id);
            console.log(name);
            console.log(price);
            console.log(supply_id);




        };


        //add to cart function
        $scope.addToCart = function (id, image, name, price, supply_id, deliver, entrega) {
            // CHAMA CART.ADD DE SERVICES 
            window.localStorage.setItem("fonecedor_carrinho", supply_id);
            window.localStorage.setItem("tipos_pagamentos", tipopag);
            window.localStorage.setItem("frete", deliver);
            window.localStorage.setItem("faz_entrega", entrega);
            cart.add(id, image, name, price, 1, supply_id, deliver);
            $state.go('nhaac.carrinho');

        };

        // animation readmore
        var fetchItems = function () {
            for (var z = 0; z < fetch_per_scroll; z++) {
                if (angular.isObject(data_ofertass[lastPush])) {
                    $scope.ofertass.push(data_ofertass[lastPush]);
                    lastPush++;
                } else {;
                    $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
                }
            }
            $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
        };



        var tipo = '';

        // $scope.checarPermissoes();

        $scope.checarPermissoes = function (tipo) {
            var permitido;

            if (tipo === 'logado_usuario' && window.localStorage.getItem("user_log") !== null) {
                permitido = true;
            } else {
                permitido = false;
            }

            return permitido;
        };




        // event readmore
        $scope.onInfinite = function () {
            $timeout(fetchItems, 500);
        };

        // create animation fade slide in right (ionic-material)
        $scope.fireEvent = function () {
            ionicMaterialMotion.fadeSlideInRight();
            ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
        };


        // animation ink (ionic-material)
        ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
        $scope.rating = {};
        $scope.rating.max = 5;
    })
```

Thank you for your time. Sorry for my english...

**EDIT:**

I think the wrong is here:

```
   <div class="card" ng-repeat="item in ofertass | filter:q | orderBy:someModel | unique: 'cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta'" ng-init="$last ? fireEvent() : null" href="#/nhaac/ofertas_singles/{{item.cadastra_oferta_cod_oferta}}">
```

Because **now I can get an array like:** ***["Temakes", "Cozinha Vegetariana"]***

But, ***How add more this filter in this ng-repeat?*** The array I called by **MeuFiltro:**

```
$scope.save = function (checkItems) {
            console.log("Chamou o save");
            var array = [];
            for (i in $scope.checkItems) {
                console.log($scope.checkItems[i]);
                if ($scope.checkItems[i] == true) {
                    array.push(i);

                }
            }
            console.log(array);

            $scope.MeuFiltro = array;

            window.localStorage.setItem("filtros", array);

            $scope.modal.hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to understand the complete problem.

But can  you try to use the selected variable in the category, when the user selects the category, it will be turned to true.

And in the section which you want to show hide, just use the filter | selected

Comment: Hi @Neha, Thank you for... I try this, but don´t work.